# Quaternion exponential map, rotations and interpolation

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, rotations, quaternions

A code snippet I need to optimize is performing something peculiar. It seems that it's somehow related to transforming from a frame of reference to another. This is what it does, in mathematical terms:

$ \mathfrak{q}_{prevToCurrExpMap} = \exp ( \mathfrak{q}_{PrevToCurr} ) $

then

$ \mathfrak{q}_{prevToCurrExpMap} = \mathfrak{q}_{prevToCurrExpMap} + \mathfrak{q}_{rotationInduction}$

and finally

$ \mathfrak{q}_{prevToCurr} = \ln (\mathfrak{q}_{prevToCurrExpMap} ) $

Essentially, the orientation quaternion's exponential map is altered by a quaternion addition, and then the result is extracted by taking the logarithm. I am trying to understand the logic behind this piece of "code", but nothing comes to mind.

Is there any obvious reason for replacing a quat $\mathfrak{q}$ with $\ln(\exp(\mathfrak{q}) + \mathfrak{p})$? (at a first glance, it does not seem to encode any kind of interpolation, but it might be trickier than it appears.)

Comment: Are you sure it's not actually doing $\ln(\exp(\mathfrak q)\cdot\mathfrak p)$ instead? That would make a lot more sense, and you never know if someone coded the right thing under the wrong function names...

Comment: Absolutely. Even so, it would be awkward to encode a quaternion addition like that by storing an exponential of another quat in $\mathfrak{p}$ (mathematically it seems feasible, but computationally is a tad mysterious).

Comment: A misguided approach based on the idea that addition is somehow "better" than multiplication ??

Comment: @bubba yes, but it makes no sense in this case. it probably should've been the other way around( $\exp( \ln(q) + \ln(p)) = q \cdot p $ ), but that's not what I see there (and yes, it would've been a disastrous way of avoiding a multiplication considering the fact that the `exp` and `ln` make use of trigonometric functions themselves).

Comment: Does the code work? How about posting it, if it's not too big.

Comment: I can't post the code (NDA). I'll try to figure out what happens further down the lane and post the formulae.

Comment: I meant that if $\mathfrak q$ is storing the *logarithm* of the actual quaternion $\exp\mathfrak q$ representing the orientation, and you wanted to post-compose another rotation represented by a quaternion $p$, the new orientation would be $\exp(\mathfrak q)\cdot p$, and you would store its logarithm $\log(\exp(\mathfrak q)\cdot p)$ in $\mathfrak q$. If someone overloaded the addition operator on the quaternion type to do multiplication instead, this would explain it.

Comment: I checked their actual implementation for `exp` and `ln`. It's disappointing, but that's what was going on wrong!! The coders actually _got them mixed_ (the `exp` is actually computing the `ln` and vice-versa). No wonder, but still a blunder. It does not make a lot of sense to encode quaternions like that and "avoid" multiplication by performing _3_ trigonometric function calls and a bucketload of normalizations. So it's not the addition encoded as a multiplication (that would have been even more confusing), but some naming error.

Comment: It's also problematic because quaternion multiplication is not commutative, and $\exp(\log p+\log q)$ equals neither $pq$ nor $qp$.

Comment: Hmm, commutativity is a real problem indeed, but I fear that here the only problem would be for $\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{q} \neq \exp(\log(\mathfrak{p})+\log(\mathfrak{q})$ to happen. The way animation uses quaternions relies on multiplication to concatenate different frames of reference. Log-encoding of this type seems like a homeopathic implementation. Do you know any cases where the above formula represents an equality? Or, at least, might be an equality in terms of unit, rotation quaternions ( via the double coverage identification at least).

Comment: On a sidenote, I guess it has to hold, but the converse is not true (i.e. if the assumption were for $ q = \ln(\exp(q))$, then the problem would've been even more obvious since this does not generally hold ). Not sure whether $\ln(p)+\ln(q) = \ln(pq)$, but I have a feeling it doesn't hold.. need to check it (at least for the subset of on $S^3$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lie algebra to the Lie group of unit quaternions is the tangent space at $1$, i.e., the set of purely imaginary quaternions. The exponential map can then be written as
$$
\exp(d)=\cos(\|d\|)+\frac{d}{\|d\|}\sin(\|d\|)
$$
The corresponding parametrization at any other unit quaternion $q$ is then
$$
q\cdot \exp(d)=q⋅\cos(\|d\|)+\frac{q⋅d}{\|d\|}\sin(\|d\|)
$$
Note that $q⋅d$ is an element of the tangent plane at $q$ to the unit sphere, and $\|q⋅d\|=\|d\|$, so that the formula might be rewritten in terms of elements of the tangent plane.

---

One interpretation of the procedure in the question (exchanging ln and exp as suggested in the comments) is that a quaternion is first cast into the tangent plane of $1$ by decomposing
$$
\mathfrak{q}_{prev}=\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\,\vec n
$$
using $c=Re(\mathfrak{q}_{prev})$, $\vec n'=Im(\mathfrak{q}_{prev})$, $\alpha=atan2(\|\vec n'\|,c)$, $\vec n=\vec n'/\|\vec n'\|$ and finally using $$\mathfrak{q}_{prevlog}=\alpha\vec n.$$

Then add the update vector and transform back using the exponential. One might keep the primary variables in the tangent plane if no modification happens in the exponential form, so that the logarithm transform is not necessary in every update step.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I still have some difficulties picturing how these computations relate to the equations on the question. Is the $\mathfrak{q}_{rotationInduction}$ stored in the tangent plane? It doesn't make sense to do it like that too much..

Comment: Yes, to be anything useful, it should be in the tangent plane. Another interpretation is that everything refers to the tangent plane of the north pole, I'll add it.